# Programmatically take screenshot of my React Native app via appetize.io

Tags: react-native, screenshot, headless-browser

I want to take a screenshot of my React Native app once a day, programmatically. It would be run by a cron job on a remote server.

The easiest way I have found is the following:

- upload my app on appetize.io (if interested, it's [here](https://appetize.io/embed/6gcx8ufjdxk61t1yf2wbdt2qe4?device=nexus5&scale=75&screenOnly=true&osVersion=7.1&location=48.8566,2.3522&orientation=portrait))
- launch a headless browser which loads the above link (I'm using puppeteer)
- tell puppeteer to wait 10s (for the app to load) and take a screenshot, or better, send `window.postMessage('saveScreenshot', '*')` as per appetize's [xDoc messages api](https://appetize.io/docs#cross-document-messages).

The only problem is, at some point, the app shows the Request Location screen:

[image]

And I cannot tell puppeteer to programmatically click on that button (or can I?). So the screenshot I get after 10s is the above one. There is a xDoc `mouseclick(x, y)` method in appetize's docs, but this seems very hacky.

Any idea how I can bypass this Request Location popup?

PS: I have also explored the following ideas of taking a screenshot of an RN app:

- react-native-web: worked after deleting some mobile-only code, but the layout for the screenshot was very broken, so didn't pursue
- run a simulator (android emulator might be easier) on the remote server, and tell it to take a screenshot. Haven't digged much into that, but it means more complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For people interested in my answer, I finally used the xDoc `mouseclick(x, y)` method to click on the Allow button.

To see the full code, please look at this file: https://github.com/shootismoke/buffer-bot/blob/master/src/getScreenshot.js